# Complex Conjugates use with n-gons and circles

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, contest-math

a) The equation of the circle centered at $1+2i$ with radius $1$ can be written as
$[ z\overline{z} + pz + q \overline{z} + r = 0.]$What is the ordered triple $(p, q, r)$?

b) Let $A_1 A_2 \dotsb A_{11}$ be a regular 11-gon inscribed in a circle of radius 2. Let $P$ be a point, such that the distance from $P$ to the center of the circle is 3. Solve $PA_1^2 + PA_2^2 + \dots + PA_{11}^2.$

I have no clue how to get started on these problems.

Comment: You could first try to write the equation of the circle with radius $r=1$ and center $(1,2)$. Use the general formula

Comment: @Isabella Where would I progress from (x-1)^2+(y-2)^2=1? I am confused at where to go from there

Comment: Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and add some minimal context and/or own work on it. Also, do not conflate multiple questions in the same post. For **a)** start with $\,|z-(1+2i)|=1\,$, and remember that $\,|w|^2=w \bar w\,$. For **b)** see the duplicate question.

Comment: Then you could expand that equation.

Comment: Do you know the answer? I think I found the solution, but I am not sure if it's correct.

Comment: @dxiv could you link that duplicate and how would you expand the magnitude of (z-(1+2i))

Comment: @Isabella The equation of the circle $\,|z-a|^2=r^2\,$ can be written as $\,z\bar z - \bar a z - a \bar z + |a|^2 - r^2 = 0\,$.

Comment: @ilikepi314 See right under `This question already has an answer here` at the top of this page.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm relatively new to Stack Exchange

Comment: @dxiv interesting, I didn't know

Comment: @dxiv  I simplified it down to z*conj(z) - (1-2i)(z)-(1+2i)(conj(z))+2. So, p,q,r would be (-1+2i,-1-2i,2) right?

Comment: @ilikepi314 Your easy question was essentially answered in the comments, and the other one marked as a duplicate. Please do not edit your post after the fact to remove the latter (as can be always seen in the [history of edits](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2932578/revisions)). Rolled back.

Comment: @dxiv I checked my work, but it seems to be wrong.

Comment: @ilikepi314 Recheck that last $+2$.

Comment: sillies all over. Ugh